# Jenkins handle node disruptions

Tags: jenkins, distributed, robustness

How can I get Jenkins to handle node connection failures?

Right now, if a slave drops the connection to the master, all the builds running on that node fail. Ideally, these would just be rescheduled.

Has someone already addressed this issue?

Do I need to write my own plugin for this? If so, where would I "extend" Jenkins functionality?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Post build task plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task):

> This plugin allows the user to execute a shell/batch task depending on the build log output.

See `http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<Your job's name>/api/`:

> **Perform a build**
>
> To programmatically schedule a new build, post to [this URL](http://Your_Jenkins/job/Your_job%27s_name/build) [`http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<Your job's name>/build`]

Comment: I suppose now I just need to know all the different things the log could say if a node goes down.